# How to get userlist from Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I've been using Telegram bot, and trying to get member list from group, but I don't know which methods I have to use for it.

https://gram.js.org/beta/classes/TelegramClient.html#getParticipants
and I found this doc, but not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

you **can`t** get the list of users of your channel via Bot API.

But you can **verify** that 'is user is member of your channel or not'

> [https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXX/**getChatMember**?chat_id="*channel_id*"&user_id="*userId*"](https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXX/**getChatMember**?chat_id=%22*channel_id*%22&user_id=%22*userId*%22)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, You can't get the list of users via Bot API.

But possible by using MTProto API (Telegram client library). A python wrapper for this is [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)!

```
client.get_participants()
```

The above method in the library is going to help you to achieve this.